# How to set up apache ranger on apple macbook pro m1

Tags: maven, apple-m1, apache-ranger

I'm trying to set up apache ranger for work using this https://github.com/apache/ranger/tree/master/dev-support/ranger-docker
however by running

```html
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

I'm getting the following error: *[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:exploded (prepare) on project security-admin-web: Execution prepare of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:exploded failed: Unable to load the mojo 'exploded' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null*  The entire error can be seen in this picture:
[1]

and as an alternative provided in the github, when I run:

```html
docker-compose -f docker-compose.ranger-base.yml -f docker-compose.ranger-build.yml up
```

I get the error:
ranger-build    | The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
ranger-build    | This environment variable is needed to run this program
ranger-build    | NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
ranger-build    | mv: cannot stat 'target/ranger-*': No such file or directory
ranger-build exited with code 1

I have also tried following https://medium.com/swlh/hands-on-apache-ranger-docker-poc-with-hadoop-hdfs-hive-presto-814344a03a17
however it gets stuck in the ranger-admin container and localhost:6080 doesn't work.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ubI.jpg

Comment: That looks like the build within your docker build fails and you need to upgrade the given plugin: `Unable to load the mojo 'exploded' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6' due to an API incompatibility:`

Comment: As I know, for Ranger version 1.X the mvn command is `mvn clean compile package install assembly:assembly -DskipTests` and for version 2.X it is `mvn clean compile package install -DskipTests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by downgrading my maven to 3.6.3 as I was having incompatibility issues, although this particular issue was resolved by adding maven war 2.6 plug in in pom.xml but then more incompatibility issues arose so i had to uninstall and reinstall a completely different maven version and that fixed all the issues.